# Increasing timeout for Server-Sent Events (SSE) connections in Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, server-sent-events, undertow

I am currently playing around with Server-Sent Events in Wildfly and sending such events to a browser via EventSource. Everything works fine, but if an SSE connection is left idle for two minutes then Wildfly closes the connection when I try to send stuff over the connection, with the following exception:

```
2023-07-11 15:22:00,282 ERROR [io.undertow.request.io] (default I/O-12) UT005088: Failed to execute ServletOutputStream.closeAsync() on IO thread: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:134)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:220)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:149)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:228)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:114)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:211)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2198)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flushBufferAsync(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:422)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.closeAsync(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:689)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl$1.run(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:662)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
    at org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)

2023-07-11 15:22:00,283 ERROR [za.co.ejb.session.esa.EsaSseService] (EJB default - 2) java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:994)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1008)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventOutputImpl.internalWriteEvent(SseEventOutputImpl.java:278)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventOutputImpl.send(SseEventOutputImpl.java:207)
    at deployment.Test.war//za.co.ejb.session.misc.SseClientRegistry.send(SseClientRegistry.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi@8.0.0.Final//org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:79)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.delegateInterception(EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:201)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:392)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityOutflowInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityOutflowInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityDomainInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityDomainInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.lambda$processInvocation$0(IdentityInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsFunctionEx(SecurityIdentity.java:421)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsSupplierEx(Scoped.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
    at deployment.Test.war//za.co.ejb.session.misc.SseClientRegistry$$$view69.send(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.Test.war//za.co.ejb.session.esa.EsaSseService.send(EsaSseService.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:416)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.IdentityOutflowInterceptor.processInvocation(IdentityOutflowInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityDomainInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityDomainInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.invocation@2.0.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1.lambda$processInvocation$0(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:83)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsFunctionEx(SecurityIdentity.java:421)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:81)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.WriteTimeoutStreamSinkConduit.handleWriteTimeout(WriteTimeoutStreamSinkConduit.java:102)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.WriteTimeoutStreamSinkConduit.write(WriteTimeoutStreamSinkConduit.java:117)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:652)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:166)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.9.Final//org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2205)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flushInternal(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:523)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.6.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:479)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$WrappedServletOutputStream.flush(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:626)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.flush(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:263)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$FlushOperation.doWork(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$AsyncOperation.work(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.flushQueue(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:331)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.queue(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:313)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.asyncFlush(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:274)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventOutputImpl.lambda$internalWriteEvent$5(SseEventOutputImpl.java:277)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2341)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:144)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@6.2.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventOutputImpl.internalWriteEvent(SseEventOutputImpl.java:277)
    ... 155 more
```

From the looks of it, it seems that this caused by some timeout setting in Undertow which I believe is around a minute.

Does anyone know specifically how to increase the timeout for SSE connections? The default timeout in undertow is probably perfect for normal REST calls. However, for SSE connections, especially if you are going to have a 100 open them open at a time, or more, the constant dropping and reconnection every minute or doesn't sound very effective.

Here is my defined endpoint:

```
    @GET
    @Path("publish/{token}")
    @Produces(SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void sseProcessed(@PathParam("token") final String token,
                             @Context final SseEventSink sink) {
        sseClientRegistry.add(Integer.parseInt(token), sink);
    }
```

sseClientRegistry is also from my code, where we keep a list of current SSE connections. If parts of the system trigger evenets, sseClientRegistry handles that and send the message to the appropriate connection.

This mechanism works ok, apart from the premature connection close due to a timeout

Comment: It sounds like you should be using the `SseBroadcaster` instead of trying to hold onto `SseEventSinks`. You may find this example helpful https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-examples/tree/main/contacts.

Comment: No, it does not, really. It rather sounds like there is a need to be specific about which clients are addressed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment above [this](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/199cbc012c7e86992a010c27b841d27c4227e52e/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/UndertowLogger.java#L75) line of code in the Undertow project, this kind of error should generally be suppressed, so that's what I did. This can be done either using the `jboss-cli.sh`:

```bash
$ ~/wildfly-31.0.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/logger="io.undertow.request.io":add(level="FATAL")
```

or by editing the `standalone.xml` configuration file:

```xml
<logger category="io.undertow.request.io">
    <level name="FATAL"/>
</logger>
```